# How can I replace the column name in a panda dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a excel file as

```
Old_name  new_name
 xyz        abc
 opq        klm
```

And I have my dataframe as like this

```
Id   timestamp    xyz  opq
1   04-10-2021    3    4
2   05-10-2021    4    9
```

As you see I have my old names as column name and I would like to map and replace them with new name as in my csv file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `rename`:

```
df.rename(columns=col_names.set_index('Old_name')['new_name'], inplace=True)

# verify
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Id   timestamp  abc  klm
0   1  04-10-2021    3    4
1   2  05-10-2021    4    9
```

Comment: what is col_names here?i get error as col_names is not defined

Comment: I read my old name and new name excel file as : df = pd.ExcelFile('ids.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')
and I have other data frame df2 which has the datapoints with column names as old name from above excel file.

Comment: `col_names` is your `df1`, `df` is your `df2`.

Comment: i get error as KeyError: "None of [Index( all new names from the excel) dtype='object', length=186)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: while I can see the old name and new name in my excel sheet and also my df2 has columns with old name